# How to find similar/related text with Zend Lucene?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

Say I need to make searching for related titles just like stackoverflow does before you add your question or digg.com before submitting news.

I didn't find a way how to do this with Zend Lucene. There are setSlop method for queries, but as I understand, it doesn't help.

Is there any way to do this kind of searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that to do related search you should just pass the query string to the $index->find method. It will find not only the exact matches but also similar ones:

```
$index->find('top 10 cars');
```

**result:**

```
Top 10 Funniest Cars
Top 11 Celebrities Cars
Top 6 Barbeque Cars
Top 10 Futuristic Concept Cars
Top 5 Classic Oldest Cars Ever
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to submit the document's text as a query.  Take the document's text, tokenize it, put an OR term in between each token, and submit it as a Lucene query.  I've done this before and it works reasonably well.

Comment: Yeah, but OR logic wouldn't help. Because it will find all documents that consist of any of these words whereas I need to find relevant documents.